# jQuery: Get attributes from "live" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create a new window when i press a button. This window contains html input elements that i want to manipulate with jquery, but i can't catch the elements. Normally i would use the live function because the html is first added to the dom when the button is pressed, but its not working.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var opretKnap = jQuery("input[value='Open window']");

    jQuery(opretKnap).live('click', function () {

            var inputsDate = jQuery("input[vdfDataType]");

    });
});
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need `jQuery(opretKnap).live(...)` here, `opretKnap` is already set to a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery("input[vdfDataType]");
```

What's `vdfDataType`? That's not a standard HTML attribute. Are you meaning to use custom attributes? (It's a generally questionable strategy, especially when you want to select on them.)

Is the element you're trying to get in the current document? You say it's a ‘new window’, but if you actually mean a new window and not an in-page DOM pop-up, you won't be able to select it from the document that opened it.

```
jQuery(opretKnap).live
```

should be [avoided](http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats):

> the .live() method should always be called directly after a selector

That is, the argument in the `jQuery()` wrapper immediately before the `live()` call should be a selector string, such as `"input[value='Open window']"` directly. `opretKnap` is a jQuery wrapper already, so `opretKnap.live()` would be OK.

```
jQuery("input[value='Open window']")
```

Avoid using `value` as an attribute selector. Apart from it not really being very specific (what happens if a text field somewhere happens to have that string in it?), it's also unreliable for many cases in jQuery.

The `value` HTML attribute and the `value` DOM property are two different things for text inputs (and some others); the property gives the current field value, whereas the attribute gives the original value that was specified in the HTML before any user input. This attribute maps to the DOM `defaultValue` property, not `value`.

However, a bug in the Sizzle selector engine used by jQuery means it'll read the `value` property in preference. This would give the ‘wrong’ (but possibly desired) results... but not consistently, because in many cases the browser's own `querySelectorAll` call will be used for speed, short-cutting Sizzle's bug.

Whilst this might not affect you (eg. if you're selecting a button, whose value will never change), you should consider the `[value=...]` selector to be highly suspect, and avoid it whenever possible. Find another way to pick the particular input you want, such as a `.class`, `#id`, `[name="something"]` or `[type=submit]` if that's what it is.